# specify which vim is called from a command like git

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, vim, zsh

I'm doing some rails dev on mac osx. I have an alias for `vim` that calls the version in homebrew

```
vim: aliased to /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/bin/vim
```

But if I execute say `git rebase -i [sha]` then it will call a different vim from the one that's aliased. It's calling `/usr/bin/vim` which is NOT what I want.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
git  config --global core.editor  /usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/bin/vim
```

Comment: although that will work, is this the best way to go about it? For example, if a different command wants to execute vim I'll have the same problem.

Comment: If your question is not just about Git, then sorry I misunderstood. Setting your `$EDITOR` environment variable to that file will get most other apps to pick it up. Putting the directory where your git resides in from of your path will enable you to call `vim` without the alias.

Comment: my fault for not wording my question better. However, I tried adding `EDITOR=my_long_path` in my zshenv and it still doesn't work. And I'm sorry I don't really understand the second part you mention.

Comment: doesn't work for what? There are bazillions of apps out there that could be trying to open an editor.

Comment: it didn't work for git. I'm trying to find a more general fix for my specific problem with git.

Comment: Didn't the `git config` thing work with git? I'm absolutely positive it works here. As for EDITOR, it _also_ works for git (just tried it again to make sure).

Comment: `git config` DOES work but EDITOR does not (unless I am doing something wrong). I am trying to look for a more generic solution (EDITOR would be it if it worked for me) but I guess this will have to do for now. Thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 1):

Create an alias (and make sure you export it) and set this as your editor of choice inside your `.gitconfig` file.

Comment: how do i make sure it's exported?

Comment: Add it to your `~/.bashrc`, for example `alias vim='/usr/local/Cellar/vim/7.3.266/bin/vim'
`.  Make sure you've loaded it by doing `source ~/.bash_profile`.  Then just list vim like you normally would in your `.gitconfig`

Answer (score 0):

On most UNIX/Linux systems, there is a variable

```
export EDITOR=/usr/bin/gvim
```

This editor ought to be used by all programs requiring input (`qmv`, `visudo`, `crontab -e`, `git commit` etc. etc.)

On debian there is

```
sudo update-alternatives --config editor
```